# JSX JavaScript Component calling another

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Intro - Hello programming community and Happy Tuesday.:) Please keep in mind I'm a newbie in JavaScript, JSX, HTML, and CSS.:)

Goal: Let me try to explain what I want to do. I have two components, one creates the dropdown list (it's a Bootstrap component) like this --

```
<DropdownButton title="People Check" id="bg-vertical-dropdown-1"></DropdownButton
```

The other is one created by me for a button on the screen.

Here's the code for the CheckIn Button

```
<CheckInButton {...some_more_props} {...self.props}</CheckInButton>{display_picture}
```

I want to be able to combine these two as each one has different things I need. I want the drop downlist to display the name and picture of the person, but upon onClick executes the data update that is already coded. Essentially each person in the the list needs to get a onClick event attached to it, as that list is being built?

The next bits of code will show the main render function that combines these two components, then the render function for the individual components.

**Main Render -**

```
return <div style={style} key={individual_id}>
   <DropdownButton title="People Check" id="bg-vertical-dropdown-1">
     <CheckInButton {...some_more_props} {...self.props}                        
     </CheckInButton>{display_picture}
  </DropdownButton>
```

**CheckInButton Render Code**

```
return <button type='button' name='checked_out' className='btn btn-success'
     onClick={this.updateMember} disabled={this.props.readOnly}>
     <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-log-out'></span>
     {this.props.buttonLabel}
     </button>;
```

DropDownlist from Bootstrap is an include on the code by this statement and creates the drop downlist. I have not touched this code and prefer not to.

```
var DropdownButton = require('react-bootstrap').DropdownButton;
```

**What have I tried**
I have tried this to attach the CheckInButton component to the onClick event --> `onClick=<CheckInButton {...some_more_props} {...self.props}></CheckInButton>`
I thought this was a long shot.

**Here's a screen shot to give a better visual.**

The checkInButton component makes the blue button and the DropDown List component puts the names and pictures in the list. The goal is to make the name and picture clickable, not have the blue button, but keep that functionalty to record the data when a picture/name is clicked in the list. Some other things to note. We use pure JavaScript mixed with JSX here in the office. Hopefully this helps.

[image]

Comment: whats the flow? click drop down and then show button ? Or click button and then update the drop down? Sorry I read your thing a couple times and couldn't grasp what you're trying to do.